# objective c array exceeding array size

Tags: c

i am working on a program that takes the data from a comma delimited txt file and putting it into a array. here's my code

So my issue is that i set the array size to 140 but the actual data is 169, but my array contains all the data and i can even set the array size to 1 and it will still put all 169 rows in. shouldnt this not be possible and shouldnt i be getting a out of bounds error?

```
char* arr[140];
char* token;
char* rest = str;
int count  = 0;
int i;
while((token = strtok_r(rest, ",", &rest))){
    char* d = token;
    arr[count] = d;
    count++;
}
//to test that the array contains the data, i print the list.
for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear whether your question is specific to the language C or Objective-C, since the topic line of your question uses the words "objective c" but the tag you use is simply "c" instead of "objective-c".

I don't know Objective-C, but in C, there is no bounds checking with the built-in array type. Therefore, your program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if it accesses an array out of bounds. This means that your program may crash, or it may not.

You may be overwriting important parts of your program (which may cause a crash at a later time) or you may be lucky that nothing important is being overwritten, so your program will still work.

Since programmers normally don't want to risk their programs to crash (or worse: have security holes), it is best to ensure that arrays are never accessed out of bounds.

Comment: i didnt realize i used the c tag. but yea i will use a properly sized array, i was just curious why it was allowing me to do that. bc i get thrown a error in other langs

Comment: @jdese001: Most other languages have out of bounds checks. However, the disadvantage of this is that these languages are also slower.

Answer (score 1):

C isn't that smart about array bounds; it will let you make those "out of bounds" assignments, which may not cause an immediate error but will likely cause problems later on.

Comment: ah ok, thank you, i dont have that much experience with c and im trying to learn it, it was confusing me bc any other language i know would tell me i cant do that